# Understanding "Useless assignment to variable"

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby function that returns a single variable subsequently used by the caller however I get the following warning

> warning: assigned but unused variable

I have put together a contrived example that will show this error with "ruby -cw"

```
def get_sum(num1, num2)
  sum = num1 + num2
end
puts get_sum(1, 1)
```

and if I check it with "ruby -cw" I get the above warning. However I am using the "sum" variable - just not in that function's scope. How can I avoid this warning? (and satisfy Rubocop too).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not using the `sum` variable for anything. The following does the same thing:

```
def sum(a, b)
  a + b
end
```

Because `sum` is local to your `get_sum` method, it is not available outside of that context.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, I'm still getting used to Ruby's way of returning the last value by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly return a value to suppress that error. Like so:

```
def get_sum(num1, num2)
   sum = num1 + num2
   return sum
end
puts get_sum(1, 1)
```

You can also shorten it a bit:

```
def get_sum(num1, num2)
   return num1 + num2
end
puts get_sum(1, 1)
```

And as you seem to have discovered, you can leave out the keyword 'return' if all you care about is the result of the last expression.

See:
[Howtogeek Ruby Function (method) Syntax](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-function-method-syntax/)